# Фильтр на PHP + mySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Всем добрый день! Есть таблица, база данных, и при загрузке страницы можно в коде задать параметр за каким будут выведены результаты (ORDER BY `***`.`***` DESC);

```
$mysqli -> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query_steklo  = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `saves` ORDER BY `saves`.`dateU` DESC");
echo $mysqli->error;
$i = 1;
while ($row = $query_steklo -> fetch_assoc()){
   $clr_code = explode('-', $row['date'])[2];
   if (is_float($clr_code/2)) {
    $clr = '#e2e2e2';
   }
   else{
    $clr = '#dbb4e2';
   }
   $saves_var = $saves_var
   ."<tr class=\"".$row['dateU']."\" style=\"background-color: ".$clr."\">"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['user']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['client']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['object']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['date']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['eur']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['rur']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['sq']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['pr']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['num']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['formula']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['materials_dop']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['materialoemkost']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['forclient']
        ."</td>"
        ."<td>"
        .$row['dateU']
        ."</td>";
     $i++;
     }
     <table class="table table-hover stekla defdiv" style="font-size: 10px"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td style="">Исполнитель</td>
                <td style="">Заказчик</td>
                <td style="">Объект</td>
                <td style="">Дата</td>
                <td style="">EUR</td>
                <td style="">RUR</td>
                <td style="">Площадь</td>
                <td style="">Периметр</td>
                <td style="">Кол-во</td>
                <td style="">Формула</td>
                <td style="">Доп.</td>
                <td style="">Мат.</td>
                <td style="">Цена</td>


            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?echo $saves_var ; ?>

    </table>
```

Надо каким - то образом при нажатии на столбик обновлять страницу с сортировкой уже за нужным параметром. 
Дисклеймер:)
НЕ прошу сделать все за меня, подскажите в какую сторону думать
Спасибо.

Comment: В заголовке столбца делаете ссылку. В ссылке прописываете параметры сортировки. Готово

Comment: хммм.. просто и четко) спасибо